# Problema con discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

hola gente estaba creando un bot para mi server y en un evento de la biblioteca `discord.py`, estaba viendo de hacer que por cada miembro que se une le dé el rango astronauta, llegué hasta acá ahora me tira name guild is not defined (supuestamente porque no añado el ctx pero no se como hacerlo)

Alguno me podria ayudar por favor o me pasan algun lugar en que sepan

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    member=discord.Member
    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == "Astronauta":
            await member.add_roles(role)
            return
            newRole = await guild.create_role(name="Astronauta")
            for channel in guild.text_channels:
                await channel.set_permissions(newRole,overwrite=overwrite)

            await miembro.add_roles(newRole)
```

Comment: Borrando la línea `member=discord.Member` y cambiando la siguiente línea por `for role in member.guild.roles:` te debería funcionar. Dicho esto, la solución que propones en tu respuesta es mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para las persoans que hayan tratado de hacer algo similar les dejo la respuesta a la que llegue

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

los import que use

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = get (member.guild.roles, name=ROLE)
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: tienen que definir role = ' ' arriba de todo de su codigo y adentro de las comillas le ponen el nombre del rol que le quieren dar